# Scoping of callback functions which modify instance variables in Dart

Tags: model-view-controller, dart, dart-async

While questions of this sort have been frequently asked, I think I have a more specific constraint that makes the problem a little more interesting. I am writing a client-side application in Dart using an MVC pattern. My goal is simple: listen for clicks on a button, trigger an async request to a back-end API, and present that data to the user.

Minimally, I have one each of a model, view, and controller class. The model class implements methods to make requests and bundle up the data it receives. The view class has the DOM subtree of interest as a field and implements methods to manipulate the elements therein. The controller has a single instance each of the model and view classes as its fields and registers event handlers on the elements of the view. The controller's event handlers fire off calls to the model to make requests and return data, which will then be passed to the view for rendering.

The issue arises when I attempt to capture the incoming data from the async request into an instance variable of the model. I'd like to keep everything nicely encapsulated (that's why I'm using Dart in the first place), and I'd like to avoid using a global variable to hold the data that comes from the async request. A minimal example of my current layout looks something like below. I've made all of the fields and methods public here for clarity's sake.

```dart
// view.dart
class FooView {
  // The root element of the view with which we're concerned.
  static final Element root = querySelector('#thisView');

  FooView() { init(); }

  void init() { root.hidden = false; }

  // Appends the new data into an unordered list.
  void update(List<Map<String,String>> list) {
    UListElement container = root.querySelector('ul#dataContainer');
    container
      ..hidden = true
      ..children.clear();
    for ( Map<String,String> item in list ) {
      container.append(new LIElement()
        ..id = item['id']
        ..text = item['text']
      );
    container.hidden = false;
  }


// model.dart
class FooModel {
  // Instance variable to hold processed data from the async request.
  List<Map<String,String>> dataList;

  // Makes async request, returning data to caller.
  List<Map<String,String>> getData() {
    HttpRequest
      .getString('example.com/api/endpoint')
      .then( (String data) {
        dataList = JSON.decode(data);
      });
    return dataList;
  }
}


// controller.dart
class FooController {
  FooModel model;
  FooView view;

  FooController() {
    model = new FooModel;
    view = new FooView;
  }

  void registerHandlers() {
    // When this button is clicked, the view is updated with data from the model.
    ButtonElement myButton = view.root.querySelector('#myButton');
    myButton.onClick.listen( (Event e) {
      view.update(model.getData());
    });
  }
}
```

The errors I'm seeing involve the `model.dataList` field coming up `null` at the end of all of this. My first blush is that I do not understand scoping of callback functions. The way I first understood it, the callback would handle the request's data when it arrived and just set the instance variable when it was ready. Perhaps the instance variable is aliased and modified within the scope of the callback, but the variable I want to return is never touched.

I have thought about passing a `Future` object to a method of the view, which will then just do the processing itself and add the elements to the DOM as a side effect. That technique would break my MVC design (even more than it's broken now in this minimal working example).

It is also very possible that I am using asynchronous programming completely incorrectly. Thinking more on this, my async call is useless because I basically make a blocking call to `view.update()` in the controller when the event fires. Maybe I should pass a request `Future` to the controller, and fire the request's `then()` method from there when the event handler is triggered.

**In Dart, in what scope do callback functions reside, and how can I get data out of them with minimal side effects and maximal encapsulation?**

*N.B. I hate to belabor this oft-discussed question, but I have read previous answers to similar questions to no avail.*

Comment: Dart uses zones to handle context: https://www.dartlang.org/articles/zones/

Comment: I haven't read your answers yet and your question not very thoroughly but I wonder why you have the HttpRequest in the model. I think this should be done by the controller.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I think, if you have a couple of model implementations. For example, one gets data from the server, another - from the local storage. And both provides common data access interface, then the controller(presenter) doesn't need to know specifics of data source.

Comment: IMHO the model can hold the information where to load the data from and where to save to but the controller should to the loading/saving. 
Another question: Have you considered using Angular or Polymer for the binding between model and view?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I agree with you about putting the `HttpRequest` in the controller. Once I did that, I have the controller handle the `Future` and update the view upon completion. Now, the model simply holds the objects that are used to render the view, instead of including the logic to make requests. I've thought about using Angular or Polymer, but this is my first Dart application and I'd like to learn the basics first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You return `datalist` in `getData` before the HttpRequest has returned.

```dart
  // Makes async request, returning data to caller.
  List<Map<String,String>> getData() {
    return HttpRequest                               // <== modified
      .getString('example.com/api/endpoint')
      .then( (String data) {
        return JSON.decode(data);                    // <== modified
      });
    // return dataList;                              // <== modified


  void registerHandlers() {
    // When this button is clicked, the view is updated with data from the model.
    ButtonElement myButton = view.root.querySelector('#myButton');
    myButton.onClick.listen( (Event e) {
      model.getData().then((data) => view.update(data));  // <== modified
    });
  }
```

Comment: This solution works. I ended up following your suggestion to move the request logic to the controller, which allowed me to be truly asynchronous! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

The `getData` method initiates the asynchronous HTTP request then immediately returns before having received/parsed the response. That is why `model.datalist` is `null`.

To make this work with minimal effort, you can make `getData` synchronous:
(note: I changed the `dataList` type, just to make it work with the sample JSON service http://ip.jsontest.com/)

```dart
// model.dart
class FooModel {

  // Instance variable to hold processed data from the async request.
  Map<String, String> dataList;

  // Makes async request, returning data to caller.
  Map<String, String> getData() {
    var request = new HttpRequest()
      ..open('GET', 'http://ip.jsontest.com/', async: false)
      ..send();
    dataList = JSON.decode(request.responseText);
    return dataList;
  }
}
```

Though this may violate your objective, I agree with your concerns re: blocking call and would personally consider keeping the HTTP request asynchronous and making `getData` return a new future that references your model class or parsed data. Something like:

```dart
// model.dart
class FooModel {

// Instance variable to hold processed data from the async request.
Map<String,String> dataList;

// Makes async request, returning data to caller.
Future<Map<String, String>> getData() {
  return HttpRequest
    .getString('http://ip.jsontest.com/')
    .then( (String data) {
      dataList = JSON.decode(data);
      return dataList;
    });
  }
}
```

and in the controller:

```dart
void registerHandlers() {

  // When this button is clicked, the view is updated with data from the model.
  ButtonElement myButton = FooView.root.querySelector('#myButton');
  myButton.onClick.listen( (Event e) {
    model.getData().then((Map<String, String> dataList) {
      view.update(dataList);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: This is similar to my answer. You can see there that you don't need to use a `Completer` for such simple cases. Just ensure that every async call is preceded by a `return` and that `then(xxx)` *returns* the result value. The completer is for cases where the chain of async calls can't be connected from begin to end. For example when you call a method that returns a `Future` and the completion needs to be done in another method (like for example an event handler - when the event was received we know the async procedure has been finished).

Comment: Agreed. I updated the example accordingly which makes the asynchronous solution of the two answers identical. Consider up-voting Günter's original version :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Stream` to make your design loosely coupled and asynchronous:

```dart
class ModelChange {...}  
class ViewChange {...}

abstract class Bindable<EventType> {
  Stream<EventType> get updateNotification;
  Stream<EventType> controllerEvents;
}

class Model implements Bindable<ModelChange> {
  Stream<ModelChange> controllerEvents;
  Stream<ModelChange> get updateNotification => ...
}

class View implements Bindable<ViewChange> {
  Stream<ViewChange> controllerEvents;
  Stream<ViewChange> get updateNotification => ...
}    

class Controller {    
  final StreamController<ViewChange> viewChange = new StreamController();
  final StreamController<ModelChange> modelChange = new StreamController();  

  Controller.bind(Bindable model, Bindable view) {
    view.controllerEvents = viewChange.stream;
    model.controllerEvents = modelChange.stream;
    view.updateNotification.forEach((ViewChange vs) {
      modelChange.add(onViewChange(vs));
    });
    model.updateNotification.forEach((ModelChange mc) {
      viewChange.add(onModelChange(mc));
    });
  }
  ModelChange onViewChange(ViewChange vc) => ...
  ViewChange onModelChange(ModelChange mc) => ...
}
```